# Distinct Record wise duplication in same column

Tags: sql, oracle

I've below sample table in which I have duplicate id received at different time stamp.
I need to have count of distinct id received in a day with number of duplicates received in that day

```
select trunc(date)  ,count(distinct id) ,COUNT(*) AS COUNTS 
from abc
where trunc(date)=trunc(sysdate)
group by trunc(date)
HAVING COUNT(*)>1;
```

Below is the table with sample data.

```
 date        id
1/1/2024    1011
1/1/2024    1012
1/1/2024    1011
1/1/2024    1014
1/2/2024    1014
1/2/2024    1014
```

and I need to get below result. I'm unable to get total number of duplicates in that day.

```
date    distinct id  no. of duplicates on that day
1/1/2024    3            2
1/2/2024    1            2
```

Comment: With `where trunc(date)=trunc(sysdate)` you'll get result for today only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use analytic functions and aggregations. Beside the number of multiple rows per date here is the number of distinct IDs that have multiple rows per date.

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl AS
        ( Select Date '2024-01-01' "A_DATE", 1011 "ID" From Dual Union All
          Select Date '2024-01-01', 1012 From Dual Union All
          Select Date '2024-01-01', 1011 From Dual Union All
          Select Date '2024-01-01', 1014 From Dual Union All
          Select Date '2024-01-02', 1014 From Dual Union All
          Select Date '2024-01-02', 1014 From Dual
        )
```

```sql
--    M a i n    S Q L :
SELECT  A_DATE, Max(DIST) "DIST", Sum(DUPL_ROWS) "DUPL_ROWS", Sum(DUPL_IDS) "DUPL_IDS"
FROM    ( Select  Distinct A_DATE, ID, 
                  Count(Distinct ID) Over(Partition By A_DATE) "DIST",
                  Count(*) Over(Partition By A_DATE, ID) "DUPL_ROWS",
                  Count(Distinct ID) Over(Partition By A_DATE, ID)  "DUPL_IDS"
          From   tbl
        )
WHERE    DUPL_ROWS != DUPL_IDS
GROUP BY A_DATE
ORDER BY A_DATE
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :
A_DATE         DIST  DUPL_ROWS   DUPL_IDS
-------- ---------- ---------- ----------
01.01.24          3          2          1
02.01.24          1          2          1   */
```

If we add some more rows to the first date:

```sql
--  added sample rows
      Select Date '2024-01-01', 1011 From Dual Union All
      Select Date '2024-01-01', 1015 From Dual Union All
      Select Date '2024-01-01', 1015 From Dual
```

... then the result would be

```sql
/*
A_DATE         DIST  DUPL_ROWS   DUPL_IDS
-------- ---------- ---------- ----------
01.01.24          4          5          2
02.01.24          1          2          1   */
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option that takes two steps.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (datum, id) as
  2    (select date '2024-01-01', 1011 from dual union all
  3     select date '2024-01-01', 1012 from dual union all
  4     select date '2024-01-01', 1011 from dual union all
  5     select date '2024-01-01', 1014 from dual union all
  6     --
  7     select date '2024-01-02', 1014 from dual union all
  8     select date '2024-01-02', 1014 from dual
  9    ),
```

Query begins here. `temp` CTE contains as many rows as sample table, but `sum` analytic function calculates number of duplicate IDs:

```
 10  temp as
 11    (select datum,
 12            id,
 13            sum(case when count(*) > 1 then count(*) else 0 end) over (partition by datum) sm
 14     from test
 15     group by datum, id
 16    )
```

Final query is simple, aggregating previously calculated values:

```
 17  select datum,
 18         count(distinct id) cnt_dist,
 19         sm cnt_dups
 20  from temp
 21  group by datum, sm
 22  order by datum;

DATUM        CNT_DIST   CNT_DUPS
---------- ---------- ----------
01/01/2024          3          2
02/01/2024          1          2

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` (self) and `GROUP BY` and count on `ROWID` as follows:

```
SELECT A.date_, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT A.ID) AS DIST_COUNT,
       COUNT(DISTINCT B.ROWID) AS DUP_COUNT
  FROM abc A
  LEFT JOIN abc B ON A.date_ = B.date_ AND A.ID = B.ID AND A.ROWID <> B.ROWID
  GROUP BY A.date_
  ORDER BY A.date_;
```

[DB<>Fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/P-eUaiQu)